# Application not recognizing package.properties in Struts2

Tags: struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

I have problem where Struts2 application is not recognizing my `package.properties`. I have no clue why. But its recognizing `global.properties` after specifying `struts.custom.i18n.resources=global` in `struts.properties`. I am using struts convention to avoid `struts.xml` configurations. My application package structure is as follows:

```
src/main/java  
     com.mysweethome
          admincustomer
               actions
          privatecustomer
               actions

src/main/resources
     com.mysweethome
          admincustomer
               package.properties
          privatecustomer
               package.properties

<s:text name="userLogin"></s:text>
```

Comment: Define properties for each user locale used with application. The user browser might request a specific locale that your application is not supporting.

Comment: What is the meaning of "Define properties for each user locale used with application".

Comment: This means you can create additional files for each locale.

Comment: Add more details (like action class, its configuration, property file content, ...).

Comment: Its resolved. After extending ActionSupport class in all the action classes then its working fine. But I don't understand how that is related to ActionSupport. I found the solution at http://www.coderanch.com/t/420317/Struts/text-Struts

Comment: @user995656 Because `ActionSupport` is where I18N stuff comes from; it supplies default implementations of a variety of things, including [TextProvider](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/TextProvider.html).